# ERROR: Error installing json: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. Windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows-10, bundle, bundler

When I run Bundle Install I am coming across this issue:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180320-1003-beh1w0.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/json-2.1.0/gem_make.out
```

I am on windows 10. How do I resolve this issue as I cannot run my cucumber tests from command line.

Answer (score 0):

> mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

Some Ruby gems need to be compiled from source on your machine. This requires additional files in your Ruby installation as well as all of the tools and libraries that the gem needs for building.

Getting all of this working on Windows on your own is very, very hard. So instead you should use the [Ruby installer](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) to get your Ruby and dev environment set up correctly.